# Тема диссертации: "Трудовые ресурсы как фактор экономического роста" нужна ли запятая перед как?

Tags: пунктуация

Стоит ли выделять запятыми в тексте "как фактор экономического роста", например, предложении: "Эволюция теории  трудовых ресурсов, как фактора экономического роста, начинается с эпохи первоначального накопления капитала.", в названии?

Answer (score 6):

Запятая не нужна. Группа подлежащего - трудовые ресурсы, группа сказуемого - фактор экономического роста. Между подлежащим и сказуемым запятая не ставится. Даже если значение сравнения: озеро как зеркало.

Answer (score 2):

Да,запятая не нужна. Здесь не сравнение, а значение "в качестве".

Answer (score 1):

В предложении *Трудовые ресурсы как фактор экономического роста* запятая не нужна (выше уже объяснили почему).

А в предложении *Эволюция теории трудовых ресурсов, как фактора экономического роста, начинается с эпохи первоначального накопления капитала* запятые нужны.

Здесь присутствует дополнительный оттенок причинности: *Эволюция теории трудовых ресурсов, будучи фактором экономического роста, начинается с эпохи первоначального накопления капитала*. (Или лучше развернуть *Эволюция теории трудовых ресурсов, которые* (либо *поскольку те*) *являются фактором экономического роста, начинается с эпохи первоначального накопления капитала*.)

Розенталь (Справочник по пунктуации для работников печати, § 42) пишет, что "некоторые случаи допускают двоякую пунктуацию", дает такой пример *Следует признать, что, как пособие для студентов, рецензируемая книга имеет ряд существенных недостатков* и поясняет "будучи пособием — с причинным оттенком значения".

P.S. Разумеется, это только размышления, не руководство к действию )

Answer (score 0):

Тут два вопроса: о запятой в названии и о запятой в тексте. Соответстввенно и отвечать надо на оба.  
Но если нужен практический совет по сиюминутной надобности, то спросите у какого-нибудь корифея там, где собираетесь защищаться. Или просто пишите без запятой в обоих случаях. Потому как вопрос спорный, но если даже, упаси Господи, вдруг приключиться такое, что у вас будут проверять правописание, то обосновать отсутствие запятых куда проще.

Ну а если хотите разобраться, обобщить, понять или даже крепко поспорить (хотя здесь это не слишком приветствуется), то попробую объясниться.

~1. Спорность запятой в заглавии определяется не сомнительностью грамматики, а авторитетом одного плодовитого писателя конца позапрошлого - начала прошлого века, творившего под псевдонимом "К. Ленин" и озаглавившего одну из программных работ "Лев Толстой, как зеркало русской революции". С тех пор немало лингвистов положило жизнь на обоснование этой запятой. Среди экономистов - я с ними в своё время немало общался как раз по вопросам диссертационной темы  - идеи Ильича всё ещё достаточно популярны, отсюда и возможные попытки влепить запятую "по образу и подобию". Но, надеюсь, это останется в моих предположениях.

~2. Вопрос обособления конструкции "как фактора экономического роста" в тексте я подробно обсуждать не буду, он спорен изначально, что и показывает здешнее обсуждение. Во всяком случае ни возможность замены "как" на "в качестве", ни тем более на "будучи" (см. ответы Marina-ja и Ларf) сама по себе определяющей не является. Здесь точно нет сравнения, точно нет случая запятой между подлежащим и сказуемым (и вообще это правило не является правилом прямого действия), но условия причинности (см. ответ Marina-ja) и признаки условия "в качестве" присутствуют в какой-то степени - и стпень эта определяется контекстом. В моём понимании оттенок причнности тут не велик, но это только по контексту можно сказать. 
Таким образом, обособление конструкции "как фактора экономического роста" - опционально.

Надеюсь, что донес мысль хотя бы в общих чертах. Но, повторюсь, для практических надобностей лучше оставить без запятых - и не заморачиваться.

Answer (score 0):

можно перед как и тире поставить